# Universal dark mode (beta)

Tags: script, design, dark-mode

## [Beta] Universal SE Dark Mode

While functional, this is experimental and while some sites work, a bit more work is required for it to support all (or, most of) SE.

[<kbd>**Install**</kbd>](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/raw/main/universal-dark-mode/universal-dark-mode.user.js)

Universal dark mode has long since been a highly requested feature, and it's a feature that I'd like. Turns out, on [Sound Design Meta SE](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1492), dark mode was released as an easter egg. But, one can take advantage of that and apply it as a base for other network sites. To activate the easter egg, one must apply the `theme-dark` class to the `<body>` tag. By doing that and patching a few other elements, one gets a reasonably good (albeit rather orange) dark mode. This userscript wraps up the easter egg and other changes into a handy script.

Screenshots:

> [image]

**License:** MIT License

**Source code:** [GitHub](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/tree/main/universal-dark-mode)